# Numbering results drawn out from database using pagination - PHP

Tags: php

Ok my is this I am creating a script for a website am designing that will using pagination to draw quotes out from database,

I have done that part quite well, setting up the pagination class and actually making it to print out the results, but I have been trying to make it print with a numbering system - as in each.

I want each quote to have its own number like:

1. "One cannot overrun his shadow";
2. "foo is not fool, just used in php"
3. "so on and so forth";

   Look at my class:

   ```
   class pagination extends cleanPost{

   var $p=1, $max_r,$limits;
   var $count_all=0,$sql,$total,$table,$totalres,$totalpages;
   var $r,$i;
   var $show=10;



   function setMax($max_r){

          $this->p = $this->clean($_GET['p']);
          $this->max_r = $max_r;

           if(empty($this->p))
           {
                $this->p = 1;
           }

          $this->limits = ($this->p - 1) * $this->max_r;

       }  
   function setData($table){

      $this->table = $table;
      $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table." LIMIT ".$this->limits.",".$this->max_r."";
      $this->sql = mysql_query($this->sql) or die(mysql_error());
      $this->total = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->table."";
      $this->totalres =  mysql_query($this->total) or die(mysql_error());
      $this->count_all = mysql_num_rows($this->totalres); // count all the rows
      $this->totalpages = ceil($this->count_all / $this->max_r); // work out total pages 
   }  



   function displayLinks($show){

       $this->show = $show; // How many links to show

       echo "<br><br>";

       if($this->p > 1) // If p > then one then give link to first page
       {
           $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">
            <a href=?p=1> [first] </a>  ";    
       }
       else
       { // else show nothing
           $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">"."";
   }
   if($this->p != 1)
       { // if p aint equal to 1 then show previous text

           $previous = $this->p-1;

       $pagination .= "<a href=?p=$previous>«prev</a>";

   }
   else
       { //else show nothing
       $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">first</span>"."";
   } 
   for($i =1; $i <= $this->show; $i++) // show ($show) links
   {

           if($this->p > $this->totalpages)
               { // if p is greater then totalpages then display nothing
               echo "";

       }
       else if($_GET["p"] == $this->p)
               { //if p is equal to the current loop value then dont display that value as link
                  $pagination .= $this->p ;
       }
       else{
                  $pagination .= " <a href=?p=".$this->p."> ".$this->p." </a>"; // else display the rest as links
       }

       $this->p++; //increment $p  
   }



   if($_GET["p"] == $this->totalpages)
       {// if page is equal to totalpages then  dont display the last page at the end of links
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">last</span>"."";
   }
   else  if($_GET["p"] != $this->totalpages)

   {
   // $pagination .= "..."; // display dots   
   #   $pagination .= "<a href=?p=".$this->totalpages.">  ".$this->totalpages." </a>"; 
   }
   else { // else display the last page link after other ones

   }
   if($_GET["p"] < $this->totalpages)// if p is less then total pages then show next link
   {
       $next = $_GET["p"] + 1;
       $pagination .= "<a href=?p=$next> next»</a>"; 
       $pagination.= "<a href=?p=".$this->totalpages."> [last] </a>"."";   
   }
     $pagination.= "</div>\n";            
   echo $pagination;
   ```

   }

   //////////
   and this is my quote display page

   ```
   $page= new pagination;
     $page->setMax(5);//set the maximum quote shown per page
     $page   ->setData("quotes");
      $page  ->display();

   echo "<table border=1 width=100%>";
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($page->sql)) 
     { 

       echo  $num_results = mysql_num_rows($page->sql);
       echo "<tr>";

     for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
   {
   echo "<td>";
    $num_found = $i + 1;

    echo $num_found.$row['ngwaquote'];
     echo "</td>";
    }
   echo "</tr>";

     }
     echo "</table><p>";
      $page  ->displayLinks(4) ;
   ```

   the results am getting is that if i click on the first number in the pagination link
   to give me
   quote.html?p=1

   I get them to list it serially
   page:1
   1[quote]A rolling stone gathers no moss.[/quote]
   2[quote]A rolling stone gathers no moss.[/quote]
   3[quote]A rolling stone gathers no moss.[/quote]
   4[quote]A rolling stone gathers no moss.[/quote]
   5[quote]A rolling stone gathers no moss.[/quote]

   but the other page quote.html?p=2 **instead of starting from**
   page:2
   6[qoute]nothing[/quote]
   7[quote]A rolling stone gathers no moss.[/quote]

   **rather** starts counting from one again
   page:1
   1[qoute]nothing[/quote]
   2[quote]A rolling stone gathers no moss.[/quote]

   I want it to appear like we have in BBC FOOTBALL blogs
   where comment page number 2 starts from 101
   instead of starting all over from 1 again

   I hope my question is not too long to understand, if that I am sorry just felt like posting them all for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over complicating the problem. Some pseudocode:

```
Current number = Number of items per page * Current page number
```

`Current page number` comes from your URL with the `?p=` GET parameter.

Then on each iteration to echo out a quote add one to the `Current number`.

Comment: at least write down a line of code it could be of great good to start from there, please?

Comment: Something like `$current_number = $items_per_page * (int)$_GET['p'];`?